# Difference between ending a `define` with or without an equal mark in a Makefile?

Tags: syntax, makefile

In a makefile, what's the difference between writing

```
define VAR =
    ...
    ...
endef
```

and writing

```
define VAR
    ...
    ...
endef
```

Notice that the latter is missing the `=` on the `define` line. Both are accepted by Gnumake, but they don't appear to exhibit the same behavior (for me, I find that using the latter does what I want it to).

When should you use which form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between them: both create recursive multi-line variable values.

There is ONE difference, though: the former version (with the equals sign) was introduced in GNU make 3.82 (released in 2010).  If you're still using a version of GNU make before that, then this statement:

```
define FOO =
bar
enddef
```

creates a variable named `FOO =`, not `FOO` (which is probably why it doesn't appear to work for you).

The ability to add assignment operators here is really so you can use the other operators, such as `:=`, `?=`, `+=` with multi-line variables, which you didn't used to be able to do.

But the default if no operator is specified is and always has been, to create a normal recursive variable.

Comment: _Aaah_, that explains it; I'm using Gnumake 3.81.